# DateTime returns wrong string on ToString(string format)

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I found a curious occurrence today:

###### Background

I was trying to load some dates from db (saved as strings) and I noticed that the datetimes fetch fails because of the format on my local db, I investicate and I discover that while the class that saves and loads those values from database always use a format string like `yyyy/MM/dd` to save, but for whatever reason dates on my db are in the format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

I investigate more and I find out that the wrong values are the one I saved while testing some new features, analyzing more I find out that all of the call to `DateTime.ToString(formatStr)` with the aforementioned format string separate the date parts with a '-' instead of a '/' as I would expect.

###### The problem

At this point I whip out a simple console program with literally 4 lines, outputs in the comment.

```cs
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")); // Ouputs 2022-10-24
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("en-US"))); // Ouputs 2022-10-24
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // Ouputs 2022/10/24
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)); // Ouputs 2022-10-24
```

I add that for all of my colleagues the result of all of the previous lines is `2022/10/24` as I would expect, my current culture is en-US at the moment.

###### Conclusion

Am I missing something? Nobody I know seems to be able to replicate this but I'm getting a lot of really funny errors beacuse of this..

Edit: Corrected code snippet

Comment: None of your `ToString` calls actually include the culture, since you've placed that inside the `Console.WriteLine` call. The invariant culture would work, as would explicitly specifying the separator through an escape sequence (`@"yyyy\/MM\/dd"`). Note that just using `en-US` would *not* necessarily work, since people using a US culture may have customized their date separator regardless. Per Tim, however, you'll want to double-check that you really need to go through string values in the first place.

Comment: "while the class that saves and loads those values from database always use a format string like yyyy/MM/dd to save" you should NEVER save a datetime as a formatted string but as  a `DateTime` in a sql parameter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert yeah typo and copy past error, corrected. So you are basically telling me that because I'm using a modified datetime format in my OS I get the wrong separator even initializing a completely new 'en-US' culture. That's good to know probably finding this now can avoind some headaches later at least.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yeah I agree with you but legacy code gonna do whatever it pleases.

Comment: Even if your legacy code cannot use parametrized queries for some reason, use the ISO or ANSI format for SQL date literals (e.g. `'2022-10-24'`) and an invariant culture for dates stored as string, because otherwise you will end up in having mixed formats in your db when your users are using different cultures. It is the UI's job to format the date in a convenient culture specific format for display.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yeah I have to admit, I have no clue why that format was chosen for saving dates in the first place I agree with all this scope of objection but sadly it's not something I can change freely at this point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "/" in date format string is not a literal, it has [special meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#dateSeparator):

> The "/" custom format specifier represents the date separator, which
> is used to differentiate years, months, and days. The appropriate
> localized date separator is retrieved from the
> DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator property of the current or specified
> culture.

So it represents *localized* date separator, and the actual symbol used depends on current or specified culture.

That means in your case `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` is "-" and not "/".

Now in your test console program, you do not pass culture to `DateTime.ToString`, you pass them to `Console.WriteLine` call, so they have no effect on formatting. Instead you should have done it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("en-US")));
```

Which will output what you expect.

You can also use format string which *always* uses "/" as separator:

```
DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
```

Update. As for why in your case with `en-US` culture you see this separator. Most likely on this machine date format has been changed manually in windows settings. `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` reflects this changes. As for manually created instances of `CultureInfo` - `CultureInfo` has several constructors, one of them is:

```
public CultureInfo(string name, bool useUserOverride)
```

That second parameter, `useUserOverride`, defines whether such changes by user will be reflected. Then, constructor you use in your example:

```
new CultureInfo("en-US")
```

Calls the constructor above with `true` as `useUserOverride`, so in this case it also reflects this changes.

If you do:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today
    .ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("en-US", false)));
```

Then it should not use those manually changed settings and then should output what you expect.

Comment: Apart from the fact that `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd", new CultureInfo("en-US")));` doesn't output what I expect, this is the answer I was looking for, I was missing that knowledge. I noticed the part about the DateSeparator property and I was starting to suspect about that, I just got confused as why I'm the only one with a different result calling with "en-US" culture.

Comment: I've extended my answer a bit about possible cause of your trouble with `en-US` culture.

Comment: Thank you @Evk I've checked and creating the culture with useUserOverride set to `false` correctly parses the DateTime object